# How do I set the screen resolution with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, windows, windows-xp

I work in one office whereby the machine is used by me 3 days per week. The other 2 someone else uses it.

By default all of the screen resolutions are set to be the (non-optimum, and very annoying) size of 1024x768.

When I come in Mon, Wed and Fri I immediately change the resolution to 1280x1024 (the max it can support, so I can see more than one window on the screen).

Is there a way of automating this so that on Monday it sets it to 1280x1024, Tuesday it reverts to 1024x768 and so on?

(Windows XP Pro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a program like this http://www.dougknox.com/xp/utils/xp_userdisplay.htm to change the resolution per user or you can use a program like this http://www.12noon.com/displaychanger.htm and execute it via Ruby.